# Step on how to add devise migration to existing User model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

I have a User model created already. I am wondering how should I configure devise with my existing User model. That being said, do I need to setup any additional routes or make atttributes accessible in my user method.

So far user model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :pic, :name, :username
  has_many :topics
end
```

My migration for CreateUsers

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :username
      t.string :pic

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now what I plan to do is run

```
rails g migration AddDeviseColumnsToUser
```

And add this to my migration file

```
class AddDeviseColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => '', :limit => 128
      t.confirmable
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.token_authenticatable
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I am wondering how should I setup my routes or do I have to ? And what attributes should be made accessible in my User model?

Update: I have already installed Devise and configured it with

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `devise_for :user` in your routes

Add `attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation`

and for more info take a look at a typical devise model

https://github.com/johndel/Rails-Simple-CMS/blob/master/app/models/admin.rb

(Pretty simple)

Comment: Should I have these both ```resources :users``` and ```devise_for :user```

Comment: `devise_for :user` does stuff like registration, login, and edit the user. It does not provide you with a profile for the user (user#show) or a list with all users (user#index). So yes, you should keep all the routes you want for your user.

Comment: Hi again, I am getting an error when running the migrations ```undefined method `confirmable' ``` . I have devise 2.2.3 installed. am I doing it the old way?

Comment: Can you show me your code? Maybe you added confirmable in your  attr_accessible and not the devise method\

Comment: its the same as I mentioned above. Or are you looking for something else? 

Update : here is what is in the user model ```devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable```

Comment: But i think its because devise does not support helper methods in anymore. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Comment: Hi, there do you know how should I create the sign up form for users here? Do I need to create new controller for User first? If so , how do I proceed with that ?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply run:

```
rails generate devise User
```

to add devise to the User model.