# Installing Devise after completing Michael Hartl's tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authentication

I'm planning on installing Devise and Cancan so I can implement some user/page authentication. I followed the Ruby on Rails Tutorial to start my website, so before I begin installing Devise, should I remove the user models/views that I already have from the tutorial? I'm not only worried about the overlap in the code and the security holes but also of breaking things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can modify your existing User model to add devise functionality.  Here's a brief [write up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns) on how to do it.

Here's a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109781/step-on-how-to-add-devise-migration-to-existing-user-model-in-ruby-on-rails)  and some [relevant discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/plataformatec-devise/x8A6OOnmHoA/JnAldWLKYckJ)