# how to Create devise for existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm creating web application in **Ruby on rails**.I have a User model created already.
Now i want create Devise to log in.

My existing dashboard_user table is

```
class CreateDashboardUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dashboard_users ,id:false do |t|
      t.primary_key :USER_ID
      t.string :USER_NAME
      t.string :NORMALIZED_USER_NAME
      t.string :PASSWORD
      t.string :LAST_NAME
      t.string :FIRST_NAME
      t.string :MIDDLE_NAME
      t.string :PHONE
      t.string :EMAIL_ID
      t.integer :SEQ_QUES_ID
      t.string :SEQ_QUES_ANSWER
      t.string :EXPIRE_PASSWORD_IND
      t.date :EXPIRE_PASSWORD_DATE
      t.string :DEACTIVATED_IND
      t.date :DEACTIVATED_DATE
      t.integer :ROLE_ID
      t.string :CREATED_BY
      t.string :UPDATED_BY
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This has been covered a number of times. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109781/step-on-how-to-add-devise-migration-to-existing-user-model-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Am using rails 4, attr_accessible not supported..

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd start by adding devise required columns: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns

Comment: I have added the devise required column such as encrypted_password and email field as username so the form normally requires username and password to sign in