# customizing devise rails to login with old login table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Can I customize devise to login using old login table(which has username, password and other things). not built using devise.

If It is possible then how to do the same.

Comment: If one of the answers has helped you please upvote/accept or explain what you're still struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Devise documentation: [How To: Change an already existing table to add devise required columns](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns)

And then see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109781/step-on-how-to-add-devise-migration-to-existing-user-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean you have extra things you wish to add into the user model? You can do this with devise using the 'sanitize' method.

I don't know how far you have gotten with Devise so I will just cover it from the beginning.

Add the gem to your gemfile, then run:

```
rails g devise:install
```

Once it is installed, generate your user model passing in anything extra you wish to add. Email and Password are added by default. In this example I will pass in a username, as a string

```
rails g devise User username:string
```

Now that the user has been generated, you can run the generator for the devise views:

```
rails g devise:views
```

This will generate a whole bunch of stuff associated with devise, but the two main things you will need are the `edit.html.erb` and `new.html.erb` view files, both found in `app/views/devise/registrations`.

In these files, add extra fields to your form, so that you can pass in the information on User sign up and User edit account.

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username %>
```

Once this is in the form, it will show up on the registration page, but it won't be saved into the users account without sanitizing the options. In your `application_controller.rb` file, you need to add the following:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
end
```

This will allow you to save the username, because you have told devise this is an allowed parameter.

Once you have it saved, you could then go on to use the :username to log in. Here is an article on how you can implement that =) > https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure OP means that he has a login system in place with usernames and passwords etc. but now he wants to switch to Devise and not lose all his users

Comment: Ah, my bad!... I'll remove my answer if this is the case! Sorry